# Web scraping difficulties for accessing html

Tags: html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this website

[scraping website](https://stock360.hkej.com/quotePlus/stockFinancialStatements/1)

I have analyzed all the XHR files and found that https://stock360.hkej.com/data/getQuotes/00002?t=1583900958659 is the data fetching site, but I have difficulties in accessing through chrome directly. It return me **unknown host found:**

Can anyone explain to me what happening deal with this HTTP GET call. I understand that 00002 is the stock number and t is the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the endpoint requires a specific header for it to work.

I found that it requires `referer` header with value of `https://stock360.hkej.com/quotePlus/stockFinancialStatements/1`

Here's the example request i sent from Postman:
[image]

Comment: Thankyou! However, do you know how the data in the table being fetched ? since I need to scrape the data in the table.

Comment: I can't find any data related to the table on the XHR sent by the page, might be server-side rendered. If that's the case, you need to do web scrapping manually by getting the HTML data and parse it, using something like beautifysoup